# Tag trust-zone is incorrect, should be trustzone

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, retag-request

The tag [trust-zone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/trust-zone) should be renamed to [trustzone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/trustzone) -- without hyphen.

Here is a link to an Arm webpage about TrustZone:
https://www.arm.com/technologies/trustzone-for-cortex-a

In the academic literature as well as in Arm documentation the term is TrustZone. No hyphen.

<sub>I know this is a minor thing, but it's an easy fix.</sub>

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yep, easy to fix; easy to undo as well if needed. Tag renamed. No synonym created.

```
updating post history, 116 rows affected (pipe delimited)
updating posts, 99 rows affected  (pipe delimited)
Target tag 'trustzone' doesn't exist, renaming 'trust-zone' to 'trustzone'
rename result: 1 rows affected
tag remapping of [trustzone] and [trust-zone] complete!
remapping 0 synonyms
48 favorite and ignored tags remapped!
0 tracked tag badges were remapped!
```